# Sending an email based on a dropdown selection in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am new to Laravel and trying to figure out how to send an email to someone based on a dropdown selection. I am using Laravel 7. I'll explain my scenario below:

On registration I am giving the user an option to select a franchise by retrieving the franchise from the database and saving the franchise ID in the user table. Upon successful registration I want to send an email to an email address that belongs to the selected franchise in order for them to approve the user.

Currently it is set to send the email to the main site admin which is not what I want.

Here is my registration function:

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {   
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'franchise_id' => $data['franchise_id'],
        ])->assignRole('User');

        $admin = User::where('Admin', 1)->first();
        if ($admin) {
            $admin->notify(new NewParentRegistration($user));
        }

    return $user;
    }
```

This is the dropdown selection in my blade file for choosing the franchise on registration:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="franchise" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Choose your Franchise</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select name="franchise_id" id="franchise" class="form-control">
                                    @foreach ($franchises as $franchise)
                                        <option value="{{ $franchise->id }}">{{ $franchise->franchise_name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

The email address I want to trigger sits in my Franchise table which has a franchise email column.

So how can I adapt the below piece of code to get the email address of the selected franchise on the registration page?

```
$admin = User::where('Admin', 1)->first();
        if ($admin) {
            $admin->notify(new NewParentRegistration($user));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `Franchise` model has `email` column defined in the database, you could send the email directly to the `Franchise`.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name'          => $data['name'],
        'email'         => $data['email'],
        'password'      => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'franchise_id'  => $data['franchise_id'],
    ])->assignRole('User');

    $franchise = Franchise::find($data['franchise_id']);
    // Notify the franchise...
    $franchise->notify(new NewParentRegistration($user));

    return $user;
}
```

Don't forget - in order for this to work, you also have to [use the Notifiable trait](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications#using-the-notifiable-trait) in Franchise model.